# C++ switch statement - jump between cases

Tags: c++, switch-statement, goto

In C++, can I do something like the code below?

In a specific case, if some conditions are met, can I jump to another case?

```cpp
switch (tag) {
    case 1: { 
        // do something
        break;
    }
    case 2: {  
        if (/* condition */) {
            // Can I somehow jump to case 1?
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: With `goto`. But it's hardly a good idea.

Comment: Not that I'd recommend doing so, but you can use `goto` and another label. May I ask what's your concrete use case / problem you want to solve that way?

Comment: or move `case 2` to before `case 1` and let it fallthrough if the condition doesn't match

Comment: If you are thinking of printing multiple things which are in multiple cases, you can use multiple if else statements and within that if statements use printf()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not really. The closest thing you can get is a conditional fall-through.

```
switch (tag) {
    case 2: {  
        // Do things that need to be done for case 2

        if(someCondition){
            // if the condition was met, we stop here   
            // and don't execute case 1!          
            break; 
        }

        // no break at the end, so we fall through to case 1
    }
    case 1: { 
        // do something
        break;
    }
}
```

But this can get very confusing very fast and is also quite limited, imo the better solution would be to write a function for each task and only use each case to call the appropriate function(s).

---

And no, `goto` is a really bad idea and no, you shouldn't even think about using it ;)

Answer (score 5):

This is not the best way but will resolve your issue.

```c
switch (tag) {
    case 1: {
    case1:
        printf("hello");
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        if () {
            // you can use goto statement
            goto case1;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As some pointed out, you can use goto. But it is not a good idea.

What you can do, and I also use this in my code sometimes, is to omit the break; statement and let several cases execute. If you decide to do so, keep a comment there, so future you
(or your coworker) won't add the 'missing' break;.

Answer (score 0):

//Use a simple while loop to iterate again the switch cases

```
int count = 0;
while(count<2) {
    switch (tag) {
        case 1: { 
            // do something
            break;
        }
        case 2: {  
            if(){
                //can I somehow jump to case 1?
                tag = 1;//reset to case 1
                ++count;
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```